# How to import generated pages into SharePoint

Tags: import, pages

I have a lot (hundreds) of pages to populate into my SharePoint site. I have a spreadsheet with page names and url's etc. Is there a way to simplify this process?

I was thinking of generating pages with their templates set etc. and then importing them somehow. Will this be possible through the "drag files here" functionality under the section as shown in the image below?

[image: Pages]

If so, what format should these files be?

If not, what suggestions do you have to generate these pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell to upload the pages. You can write a PowerShell script that will look at the spreadsheet, download or grab the file in the cell for the row, and upload it to the document library that you specify.

That honestly (based on the # of files) would be the best way of carrying out that task.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so what I still don't know is what should the files themselves look like that I upload?

Comment: They aren't already files? The url isn't the path?

Comment: No, it is the local url where the page should live. I can try to generate the pages, but I don't know what the format should be or where to find out what the format should be.
Is there a way to see what an empty page based on a specific layout would look like and then uploading files with that format?

Comment: That's way too complex. What are you trying to ultimately accomplish here? Why are you generating pages? You could generate html files fairly easy.

Comment: Ok (thanks for your patience). So I have 4 layouts loaded in sharepoint. I also have 1 exel file that tells me what layout I should use for the content (text only - some in txt, some on old html site) and what the resulting page name is and where it should be located.

So what I want to do is instead of going into sharepoint and creating each page manually, selecting the layout to use, I want to write a script to generate & import whatever I need to have the correct page with the correct layout in the right place (url). I hope this makes sense now?